# Kids cannot access gold content with Xbox Live Gold Sharing

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

We have an Xbox One, and an Xbox Live Gold membership, which is tied to my account.  My two kids have separate Microsoft accounts that they sign in to when they play on the Xbox, at least for most games.

Although I have my Xbox set as the Home Xbox, the Gold does not appear to be sharing with the other accounts.  Specifically, they cannot access any area of Destiny that requires XLG, and they have to sign in as me to play PvZ: Garden Warfare at all.

Is there something else I have to do to share the XLG with the other accounts on the console?  If not, what did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: do you have parental settings applied?

Comment: @ZeroStack Yes I do.

Comment: can you temporarily turn if off for testing?

Comment: @ZeroStack Adjusting the controls from the most restrictive setting (Child) to a less restrictive setting (Teen) appears to have solved at least the Destiny issue.

Comment: How about for the PvZ ?

Comment: @ZeroStack Could not find the disc (damn kids) so started the backward compatibility update.  Will have to wait until they get home to test it, but will report back.  If it fixes it, feel free to move your comments to an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we found out in the comment discussion, the parental settings on your Xbox were blocking the Xbox Live features of Destiny.   Once you changed this to a less-restrictive setting, their profiles were able to load Destiny.

Specifically, from the adult account (prior to Nov 12, 2015 update):

1. Go to Settings
2. Choose the child account to change (far right)
3. Change setting from "Child" to "Teen" (or "Adult")

Comment: Tried this, but after the above steps and restarting PvZ, when I try to select "Garden Ops" it still says "Connection: Your profile does not have the correct permissions to access XBox Live functionality".

Comment: Oh, re-reading this it appears that this did not fix the PvZ issue, did you ever figure out how to let them play that without being you?

Comment: @Michael That problem seems to be on the EA side, and I never bothered, as GW2 came out and they handle the logons differently.  There was another EA game giving them grief, but not enough to force me to go through the trouble yet.